# regexp_substr - аналогия для PostreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldeveloper

Имею атрибут "Request", вот примерно такого содержания:

```
<a href="https://help.company.ru/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$1461278">INC106141</a>
<a href="https://help.company.ru/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$1461278">INC10643</a>
```

хочу получить результат только INC и цифры которые за ним следуют. Результат как в примере был бы таким:

```
INC106141
INC10643
```

На SQL Developer я бы задал бы это вот так:

```
select regexp_substr(link, 'INC[0-9]+')
```

Есть ли подобные аналогии на PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользуйтесь функцией
[`SUBSTRING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html):

```sql
WITH t(request) AS (
  VALUES
    ('<a href="http://example.com">INC106141</a>' )
  , ('<a href="http://example.com">INC10643</a>' )
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(t.request FROM 'INC[0-9]+')
  FROM t
;
```

Результат:

```
 substring 
-----------
 INC106141
 INC10643
(2 rows)
```